# Assigning the result of a SQL query to a variable?

Tags: python, python-3.x, sqlite

I am trying to add to a numerical variable the result of an SQL query in a py script.
Below is the part of the script:

```
cur.execute("select count() from tanulo")
    szam = cur.fetchone()
    print (szam)
```

When run this script, I get as a result:

(182,)

How can I get this result as an integer number?
I want then with this number do other things in the script.
It should be an integer number and should be added to a variable.

Update:
I changed the code to this:

```
cur.execute("select count() from tanulo")
print ()
szam = cur.fetchone()
print ("A tanulók száma: %d." % szam)
```

Now I get output like this:

```
A tanulók száma: 182.
```

Great! I just do not know how to get this number 182 into the variable 'szam'?
I want to get it like this:

```
szam = 182
```

Comment: This is explained in the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sqlite3.html).

Comment: Did you mean bellow this header?  '12.6.6.3. Converting SQLite values to custom Python types'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I find the solution with somebodies help:

```
cur.execute("select count() from tanulo")
szam = (cur.fetchone()[0])
szam = szam + 1
print (szam)
```

The output of this code is
183
so the 'szam' variable is now an integer.